# EM Algorithm for Mixed Poisson Model

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have been tasked to implement an EM algorithm to fit a mixed Poisson model,

\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \pi\left[\frac{e^{-\lambda_1}\lambda_1^x}{x!}\right] + (1 - \pi)\left[\frac{e^{-\lambda_2}\lambda_2^x}{x!}\right]
\end{equation}

I'm given some simple tabular data

```
    x  x=0  x=1  x=2  x=3  x=4  x=5  x=6  x=7  x=8  x=9  x=10+
#days  162  267  271  185  111  61   27   8    3    1    0
```

Where #days represents the number of days (out of 1096: 2 years and 1 leap year) that an event occurred x times. I.e. There were 162 days in which the event did not occur at all, 267 where the even occurred on time, Etc.

I'm really not sure how to apply the EM algorithm or for what exactly I'm solving. Could anyone walk through what the EM algorithm would look like in this case? What are my initial values for $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2$ ?

I've tried working through some literature but it's been pretty challenging to pull insights out of it.

Comment: A good place to start would be listing the steps of the expectation-maximization algorithm.

Comment: Also, are you trying to optimize over just $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ or also over $\pi$?

Comment: @Math100 Ok, I'll try to start with that. I believe all three parameters, none of them are given.